# Ruby on Rails, MySQL and Snow Leopard

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, osx-snow-leopard

I have working fine my installation of Ruby on Rails on my Snow Leopard. I've tried for several days install MySQL with Ruby on Rails, all I've got when I run:

```
rake db:create
```

is:

```
(in /Users/naikon/RoR/test2)
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_init
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.4/ext/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_init
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.4/ext/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap
```

I've tried with MySQL 32 and 64 bits (and deleting all several times), install mysql gem in all the ways I've found on the internet, including

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

I'm lost, frustrated and I really appreciate some help.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you install MySQL initially (i.e. using the DMG or from source)? Can you create a database manually through the MySQL console?

Comment: I installed MySQL from DMG source, and MySQL works correctly. quest was right in his answer, the correct gem is mysql2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well lets start off with the fact your building the incorrect gem.

From your error report it appears your using Rails 3, and this doesn't use the "mysql" gem at all. It uses the mysql2 gem which offers a number of performance features.

You can read more about the mysql2 gem at http://github.com/brianmario/mysql2

I think you will be fine once you install the correct gem. =)

Comment: It Works! Really appreciated quest, you've made my day ;)